# How to make the x-labels more readable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

So I have a ***Time-Series*** plot, but the problem with it is that the x labels are one over the other, and I'm wondering how to correct it?

Here's the code:

```
def time_series(start, end):
    time_series_df = Res[['Timestamp', 'Ammonia']][(Res['Timestamp'] >= start) & (Res['Timestamp'] <= end)]
    x = time_series_df.Timestamp
    y = time_series_df.Ammonia
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Ammonia Value')
    plt.title('Ammonia Time Series')
    return plt.show()
```

And when I display it:

```
time_series('2013-11-01 00:00:00','2013-12-31 23:00:00')
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

Comment: Do the dates have to have that format? Or would it be fine to have a shorter format?

Comment: i'm sorry but , In which sense , a shorter format ?

Comment: you can rotate the labels like this: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested in a comment on your post, you could rotate the labels with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

x = random.sample(range(1, 10000), 100)
y = random.sample(range(1, 10000), 100)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.xticks(rotation = 40) # 40 is the rotation angle
plt.show()
```

[image]

As described on the matplotlib [references](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html).